# How to use select statement insted of update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL server 2014. in my database i have one 'Range' as a column name 
so while saving data for this column i have three input like 'Low','Medium','High'
but in Database i am storing this value as 'L','M','H'
But when i want to display this value on report i want to show L=Low,M=Medium,H=High 
So i created Temporary table #TblRange
and i update the table as follows:

```
   update #TblRange
   set Range=(CASE
          WHEN  Range= 'M' THEN 'Medium'
          WHEN  Range= 'H' THEN 'High'
         WHEN  Range= 'L' THEN 'Low'
         end )
```

My question Is is there any way that i can avoid creating temp table and only select statement can do this job?

Comment: pl don't use CAPS, as whether you right in caps or not, users will read it and if you want to highlight then you can either mark it as bold or italics to put emphasize on something.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela I have remove CAPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write Case in Select statement :

```
Select   (CASE Range 
          WHEN  'M' THEN 'Medium'
          WHEN  'H' THEN 'High'
         WHEN   'L' THEN 'Low'
         end ) as Range from TableName
```